Extract the Procurement URL from TED using SPARQL query?
I am trying to use SPARQL query to get the procurement URL or etenders Resource ID from TED
import sparqldataframe
import pandas as pd

# Define the SPARQL query
sparql_query = """
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX epo: <http://data.europa.eu/a4g/ontology#>  
PREFIX cccev: <http://data.europa.eu/m8g/>  
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>  
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?publicationNumber ?legalName ?publicationDate ?title ?description 
                ?accessURL ?submissionAddress ?procurementDocumentURL ?announcementURL WHERE {
  
  GRAPH ?g {
      ?notice a epo:Notice ; 
        epo:hasPublicationDate ?publicationDate ;
        epo:hasNoticePublicationNumber ?publicationNumber ;
        epo:announcesRole [  
          a epo:Buyer ;  
           epo:playedBy [
                  epo:hasLegalName ?legalName ;
                  cccev:registeredAddress [
                    epo:hasCountryCode ?countryUri
                ] 
            ]  
        ] ;
        epo:refersToProcedure [
            dcterms:title ?title ;
            dcterms:description ?description 
        ] .

      OPTIONAL { ?notice dcterms:accessRights ?accessURL . }  # Access Rights might not be the correct predicate
      OPTIONAL { ?notice dcterms:relation ?submissionAddress . }
      OPTIONAL { ?notice epo:hasDocument ?procurementDocumentURL . }  # Check if this is the correct predicate
      OPTIONAL { ?notice dcterms:isReferencedBy ?announcementURL . }  # Use a more relevant predicate for announcement URLs
  }
  
  ?countryUri a skos:Concept ;
      skos:prefLabel "Ireland"@en .

  FILTER(CONTAINS(LCASE(STR(?legalName)), "dublin city council"))
} 
ORDER BY ?publicationDate
"""

# Execute the SPARQL query
endpoint_url = "https://publications.europa.eu/webapi/rdf/sparql"
df = sparqldataframe.query(endpoint_url, sparql_query)

# Display the results
if not df.empty:
    print("Tender Details with URL Fields for Dublin City Council:")
    print(df[['publicationNumber', 'legalName', 'publicationDate', 'title', 'description', 
               'accessURL', 'submissionAddress', 'procurementDocumentURL', 'announcementURL']])
else:
    print("No tenders found with URL fields for Dublin City Council.")

This is the result that I have managed to get so far:

I have tried to discover what the url field name is looking at Excel exports and Schema documents available from the TED website.
https://docs.ted.europa.eu/ODS/latest/reuse/_attachments/TED-XML_general_description_v2.0_20160219.pdf

I am not able to find a code example that returns the url on the GitHub supporting documents.
https://github.com/OP-TED/ted-rdf-docs/blob/main/notebooks/import-into-dataframe.ipynb
